# Why is $H^*(K(\pi, 1); A) \cong \text{Ext}^*_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]}(\mathbb{Z}, A)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

As the question title suggests, what is the easiest way to see that there is an isomorphism$$H^*(K(\pi, 1); A) \cong \text{Ext}^*_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]}(\mathbb{Z}, A)?$$

Comment: If you're looking for a reference, it may help to know that the RHS is equal to the group cohomology $H^*(\pi, A)$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the cohomology of a $K(G,1)$ group cohomology?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10512/why-is-the-cohomology-of-a-kg-1-group-cohomology)

Answer (score 1):

Take $CW$-decomposition for your space $K(\pi,1)$. For universal covering $B_\pi\to K(\pi,1)$ you can construct according $CW$-decomposition.

Note that $\pi\,\,$ *free* acts on the $B_\pi$, and the factor $B_\pi/\pi$ will be homeomorphic to $K(\pi,1)$. This action respects $CW$-complex structure, so cochain complex $C^\bullet(B_\pi,A)$ is complex of free $\mathbb Z[\pi]$-modules with zero $n$-th homology, $n>0$, and $0$-th homology $=A$. The $\pi$-invariant elements of $C^\bullet(B_\pi,A)$ is just $C^\bullet(K(\pi,1),A)$, therefore

$$H^\bullet(K(\pi,1),A)=H(\{\text{$\pi$-invariant subcomplex of } C^\bullet(B_\pi,A)\})=:\mathrm{Ext}^\bullet_{\mathbb Z[\pi]}(\mathbb Z,A).$$